# Instalar y direccionar librerias para dos versiones de python instaladas

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, virtualenv

Necesito realizar una conexión y/o comunicación entre un software y Python, pero ese software solo puede trabajar con Python 3.4 o una versión menor, y tengo instalado Python 3.7 desde hace mucho tiempo (lo instale con Anaconda).

Mi idea no es desintalar Python 3.7 sino que utilizar Python 3.4 con las librerías necesarias.
Lo que he hecho es instalar python 3.4 y el .exe lo agregue a las variables de entorno del sistema. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero ahora necesito instalar numpy para utilizarlo con Python 3.4.
Utilizando pip3.4 (que también fue agregado al path) trato de instalar numpy pero no me funciona.

Mi idea es tener por separado las librerías de Python 3.7 (que ya están instaladas por Anaconda) e instalar las que necesite para Pythonn 3.4

He visto que utilizan entornos virtuales para tener aislado versiones de Python y sus librerías, pero no se si al realizar eso me traerá complicaciones cuando deba intercambiar información entre Python 3.4 y el otro software que utilizare.

Cualquier información y/o consejo me sera de mucha ayuda
Gracias

Saludos

Comment: Hola Juan, personalmente no me gusta añadir pip al PATH y ejecutarlo directamente, sino ejecutalro como cualquier otro módulo a través del intérprete en el que quieras instalar de forma explícita. Si tienes Python 3.4 en el path bastaría con hacer `python3.4 -m pip install numpy` o usando [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) `py -3.4 -m pip install numpy`. En extremo se puede usar la ruta directa al interprete `ruta/a/python34/python.exe -m pip install numpy`. Esto es más seguro y explícito que lanzar pip directamente.

Comment: Al parecer tengo problemas con python3.4, no me deja instalar numpy.
Realice tus ejemplos con python 3.5 y funciona bien

Comment: ¿Exactamente que problema te da?¿Se lanza pip?¿Descarga NumPy?¿Da un error al compilar?¿de dependencias?

Comment: ejecuto lo siguente C:\Python34>python.exe -m pip install numpy.........resultado: File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Python 3.5 or later is required")
RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required

Comment: Revisando mejor creo que es pip el que tiene el prooblema

Comment: Si creo que es pip, ya que al ejecutar el comando .... python.exe -m pip --version.... dentro de la carpeta de Python 3.4 manda el error que escribí anteriormente. (con esto verifico si pip funciona bien)

Comment: Python 3.4 ya ha alcanzado su end-of-life, las versiones actuales de pip no tienen soporte para el mismo... ¿Por casualidad actualizaste pip de esta versión tras instalar? Supongo que siempre podrías descargar numpy y sus dependencias (versiones compatibles con python 3.4) e instalar sin pip ejecutando directamente el setup.py

Comment: No me percate si pip se actualizo al momento de instalar. 
Hare el intento con el setup.py (nunca he instalado nada asi)